# React Notiifcation Hook Stuttering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I made a hook that i use for a simple notification type system. But whenever I spam the notifications it starts like bugging out/jittering out.

I will give a gif example below:

[image]

Okay, so let's get down to the actual code itself:

This is my react hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default () => {
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);  
    const addNotification = (notification) => setNotifications([...notifications, notification]);
    const deleteNotification = (id: number) =>
        setNotifications(notifications.filter((m) => m.id !== id));
  
    return { notifications, addNotification, deleteNotification };
};
```

This is my Notification Item

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import '../components/App.css'

  interface INotificationItem {
    notification,
    deleteNotification(id: number): void;
  }
  
  export default (props: INotificationItem) => {
    const { deleteNotification, notification } = props;
    const { id } = notification;
  
    const [alive, setAlive] = useState(true);
    const [fadeOut, setFadeOut] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => setAlive(false), 2000);
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };
    }, []);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!alive) {
        setFadeOut(true)
        setTimeout(() => {
            deleteNotification(id);
        }, 300)
      }
    }, [alive, deleteNotification, id]);

    return (
    <div className={fadeOut ? "notification top-right-out" : "notification top-right-in"}>
    </div>
    );
  };
```

And for the last, is my app.tsx main file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'
import useNotificationManager from '../hooks/useNotificationManager';
import NotificationIItem from '../items/NotificationIItem';

const App: React.FC = (props) => {
    const { addNotification, deleteNotification, notifications } = useNotificationManager();
    const [notificationInd, setNotificationInd] = useState(0);

    const addNotification = () => {
      addNotification({ id: notificationInd});
      setNotificationInd(notificationInd + 1);    
    }


    return (
        <>
        <div className="top-right-in" style={{position: 'fixed', boxSizing: 'border-box'}}>
        <div className="column-wrap top-right-in" style={{display: notifications.length > 0 ? 'flex' : 'none', flexDirection: 'column-reverse'}}>
        {notifications.map((notification) => (
            <NotificationIItem
              deleteNotification={deleteNotification}
              notification={notification}
              key={notification.id}
            />
        ))}
        </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

CSS:

```
.column-wrap {
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

@keyframes toast-in-right {
    from {
      transform: translateX(100%);
      
    }
    to {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes toast-out-right {
    from {
      transform: translateX(0);
      
    }
    to {
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}

.notification-container {
    font-size: 14px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
}

.top-right-in {
    top: 12px;
    right: 12px;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    animation: toast-in-right .5s;
}

.top-right-out {
    top: 12px;
    right: 12px;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    animation: toast-out-right .5s;
}

.notification {
    background: #fff;
    transition: .3s ease;
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 6px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
    color: #000;
    opacity: .9;
    background-position: 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I have a feeling it's either something in the hook itself, when it's deleting the notifications or when I actually call it and increase the notification index.

Anyways, I hope someone with fresh eyes maybe sees the simple mistake i may of done.

Thanks, and kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your CSS to fully reproduce the issue, but even without it I noticed some *odd* rendering issues.

They appear to be completely resolved, however, by using functional state updates.

Example:

```
const useNotificationManager = () => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

  const addNotification = (notification) =>
    setNotifications((notifications) => [...notifications, notification]);

  const deleteNotification = (id: number) =>
    setNotifications((notifications) =>
      notifications.filter((m) => m.id !== id)
    );

  return { notifications, addNotification, deleteNotification };
};
```

[image: Edit react-notiifcation-hook-stuttering]

### Update

In an attempt to optimize here are a few tweaks:

1. Remove the `alive` state and call a delete handler to handle removing the notification.

   ```
   const NotificationItem = (props: INotificationItem) => {
     const { deleteNotification, notification } = props;
     const { id } = notification;

     const [fadeOut, setFadeOut] = useState(false);

     useEffect(() => {
       const handleDelete = () => {
         setFadeOut(true);
         setTimeout(() => {
           deleteNotification(id);
         }, 300);
       };

       const timer = setTimeout(handleDelete, 2000);
       return () => {
         clearTimeout(timer);
       };
     }, []);

     return (
       <div
         className={
           fadeOut ? "notification top-right-out" : "notification top-right-in"
         }
       >
         {id}
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```
2. Use a function to generate `id` values; remove the `notificationInd` state.

   ```
   let id = 0;
   const generateId = () => id++;
   ```

   ...

   ```
   const addNotification = () => {
     addNotification({ id: generateId() });
   };
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will go ahead and test this right now. And I'll update the post with the CSS.

Comment: Update - Seems to still be doing what it was doing in the screenshot.

Comment: @infamoushvher I've added your CSS and I think I see what you mean. I think the issue now is animating/transitioning the notifications vertically. You could prepend new notifications (*add to the front*), and they look great and smooth transitioning in... but now they "stutter" when exiting. It's not really stuttering that you are seeing, but rather sudden change in "y-coordinate". I'll see if I can tinker a bit.

Comment: Also tried your optimizations, and that didn't really help with the jittering aswell.

Comment: @infamoushvher Perhaps I'm not quite understanding what you are calling "jittery". It all seems to run smoothly on my end. Can you clarify more precisely the issue?

Comment: It's still doing the exact same thing It shows in the gif I attached to this post

Comment: @infamoushvher I guess that's what I mean. What *exactly* is stuttering in the gif? I see toasts smoothly transition in from the right, and get pushed down (*albeit a little suddenly*).

Comment: Not stuttering per say, but it does not look good. And it seems to be bugging out can you not see this? (when there is alot of em at the same time it tends to just bug out and not do the smooth transition as displayed in the gif)

Comment: @infamoushvher I ran into some buggy behavior involving the second timeout in your code and not clearing it, but that seemed resolved by using a single timeout cleared in an effect cleanup function. From a quick google search, it seems the solution for transitioning the toasts vertically involves animating/transitioning the toast container's height attribute. I can play around to see if I can come up with something a little "smoother" when I get some time.

Comment: Hey, seem to have solved the issue by using the modified hook you gave me. But removing the optimizations made it work. So only the hook worked for me to make it work smoothly didn't need anything else. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: @infamoushvher Are you saying that my answer, part of it, has sufficiently addressed/resolved your question/issue?

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying.